# SQLite Database Search Not Returning Rows

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a method where I want to pass a String into it and search the database for matches. I'm new to databases so I'm at my wits end. I have been googling and trying different query's for a few days now and its just not working. The cursor is created just fine so I don't THINK there are any syntax problems with the query. The cursor is not null, there is a Cursor object in there and there are all 3 columns in there too. But there are no rows. When I pass in a String where I know there should be a match it just doesn't return any data. Here is the method:

```
public Business getBusiness(String search) {
    File database=currentContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
    SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(database.getAbsolutePath(),     
                                                        null, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {COLUMN_ONE, COLUMN_TWO,        
                             COLUMN_THREE}, COLUMN_ONE + " like ' " + search + " '", 
                             null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Business business = new Business(currentContext, cursor.getString(0),  
                                     cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),  
                                     cursor.getInt(3), cursor.getInt(4));
    db.close();

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your like statement to include a wild card(s)

For example change from

```
" like ' " + search + " '"
```

to

```
" like ' " + search + "_'"
```

or

```
" like '_" + search + "_'"
```

A percent symbol ("%") in the LIKE pattern matches any sequence of zero or more characters in the string. An underscore ("_") in the LIKE pattern matches any single character in the string.

Trust this is of assistance. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you have try this code ... this code run properly ..

```
Cursor cursor;

            try
            {
                cursor = db.query
                (
                        TABLE_NAME,
                        new String[] { TABLE_ROW_ID, TABLE_ROW_ONE, TABLE_ROW_TWO, TABLE_ROW_THREE, TABLE_ROW_FOUR, TABLE_ROW_FIVE, TABLE_ROW_SIX },
                        TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID,
                        null, null, null, null, null
                );

                cursor.moveToFirst();

                if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
                {
                    do
                    {                   
                        String row_item_id=cursor.getLong(0);
                        String row_item_name=cursor.getString(1);
                        String row_item_basic_price=cursor.getFloat(2);
                        String row_item_tax=cursor.getFloat(3);
                        String row_item_shipping=cursor.getFloat(4);
                        String row_item_price=cursor.getFloat(5);
                        byte[] imgByte = cursor.getBlob(6);
                            Bitmap row_item_bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte, 0, imgByte.length);

                    }

                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```